# User Login Session throughout Application run

Tags: android, session

I wanted to create a user login session still user not like to logout untill Login Activity doesn't appear throughout application whenever run. So please give me some guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save data in sharedprefrence and when logout clear the preference

use this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do so 
1. save user details in file.
2. use sharedprefrence.
3. use database to store user information.

on first time running of application ask user to save details.
after that on every Start Up of application prompt user to enter details like user id and password and then compare these with stored details 
if details are matched then next part of application will be loaded, else exit from the app or ask to re enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add it to the Bundle and pass that bundle data to every activity, if you don't want it to store in a database/shared preference